# android studio was unable to recognize the apk(is) currently installed on the device

Tags: android, android-studio

- Android Studio: 3.5.3
- Android Gradle Plugin: 3.5.3
- Gradle: 5.6.1
- Build Variant: Debug
- MinSDK: 18
- TargetSDK: 28
- CompileSDK: 28
- MutiDex: enabled
- PhysicalDevice: Pixel 4 XL with Q

**Apply Code Change** failed and this is the log:

```
android studio was unable to recognize the apk(is) currently installed on the device
```

what would cause this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solved**

It caused by an third-part aar library which dynamically load an dex file on application start. I think Android Studio "Apply Changes" compare current dex with it's last build cache, but when you dynamically modified dex file, it won't be able to install changes. Correct me if you think I'm wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Try to uninstall the app from the device and just build the Gradle again to install the app in your device. So that you can again apply the changes to the code. 
This isn't a error it sometimes happens due to some internal changes in the OS

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I tried that, but it didn't work. And I just found out it caused by a third-part aar library.